# who updated the stored proc?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to check who was the last person or list of people who update a given proc in SQL server 2008? Is there a built in utility command, dash board, or 3rd party tool out there which can provide this insight?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have separate usernames in your sql server?

Comment: I am sure this question is to address an issue that has already happened and @Will A gives a solution to this for near term changes, however I have seen the following implemented which allows schema change logging to be persisted for the longer term: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the database node in SSMS, choose Reports>Standard Reports>Schema Changes History.  This'll give you a list of changes - however, if the changes was not made recently you may not be able to find it on this report - it does not show "all changes, ever"!

Comment: We all login with sql server authentication and every one uses same credentials so in our case its hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates you have several troubling problems that need to be addressed.

First you should be using source control and storing all changes to procs in it. Then you can see who made what change and be able to revert to previous versions.

Next, if this problem occurred on production, you need to limit the production rights to only a dba and people assigned a configuration management role (Either configuration pepeople, dbas, or managers). Application developers should not have any rights to create or update objects on prod at all.

You can also set up trigger to monitor and record all changes to databases. Look up DDL triggers.

@Will A gives you a short-term solution but it may not be valid for the research you need if the change was not recent.